# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError" while using import spacy in jupyter notebook and in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, spacy

While using spacy on jupyter notebook and in the Ubuntu terminal, I am getting an error message:

[image]

[image]

Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Spacy is dependent on tqdm.
Please install tqdm and restart the Jupyter kernal.

Installation for conda: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tqdm

Installation for Pip: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

Comment: Thanks, it worked. After installing tqdm, I have to install wasabi,catalogue, and plac. Then it is working on both the notebook and in the terminal.

Comment: great! Python usually gives you a good indication with its exception name; in this case ModuleNotFoundError.